# Multiple definition error in static compilation with g++ under cygwin

Tags: c++11, g++, cygwin

I am trying to compile a large codebase with g++ under cygwin. Compilation fails, and I have reduced the problem to the following self-contained test case:

file main.cpp:

```
#include <stdexcept>
int main() {
  std::logic_error One("One");
  std::logic_error Two(One);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation command and result:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -static main.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libstdc++.a(cow-stdexcept.o): In function `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::logic_error const&)':
/usr/src/debug/gcc-6.4.0-1/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/cow-stdexcept.cc:59: multiple definition of `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::logic_error const&)'
/tmp/ccCSKFES.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt11logic_errorC1ERKS_[_ZNSt11logic_errorC1ERKS_]+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The file compiles and links on CentOS with g++ 5.3.1 and 6.3.1. It fails to link under cygwin with g++ 6.3.0 and 6.4.0. It always compiles and links if I omit the flag "-static".
Is this a bug in g++ under cygwin, or is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
g++  -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -static -Wall main.cpp
```

But if I remember right C++ exceptions do not work very well with a static build on cygwin.